# Союз "как"

Tags: лексика, как

Уместно ли писать союз «как» в таком контексте: "...говорить о ней (в том значении, как это выше сказано)..."

Answer (score 1):

А нельзя как-нибудь по-другому?  
Потому как может и можно, но лучше не надо. В принципе "как" может в разговоре подменять и "который", и "что", и многое другое, но здесь как-то уж очень по ушам бъёт.